# grep not working while reading input from a file

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to find a key in a directory using grep.
No. of keys is huge so I have stored them in a `keys.txt` file and reading one line at a time.
final_modules directory is to be searched.

when we run for one key from terminal it is found.

```
$cd ~/Unsed_key_task/final_modules
grep -r <KEY>
```

but when same key is iterated through the file below it is not found.

```
keys.txt>>
  key1
  key2
  key3
  ...
  ...
```

and
 greps.sh >>

```
   FILENAME=$1     
    while read LINE
            do
                    cd ~/Unsed_key_task/final_modules
                    let count++
                    echo $LINE
                    pwd
                    grep -r $LINE

                    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
                    then
                            echo " found"
                    else
                            #echo "not found"
                            echo $count
                            echo  $LINE
                            echo "     [ Not found ]"
                    fi
   done < $FILENAME
```

When I print `$LINE` it prints right  and also `pwd` prints the right directory.
my code finds just one key and exits.

Comment: To grep using patterns from a file, use `grep -f patterns_file file`.

Comment: thanks, but why is this not working.even though $LINE is getting the right value?

Answer (score 3):

`grep` can read patterns from a file. You don't need to iterate over `$FILENAME` on your own. What you want to achieve can be done with this simple command:

```
grep -f "$FILENAME" -r
```

Comment: will it search one line from "FILENAME" at a time ??

Comment: try it! :) Does it fit your requirements? (Probably you want to do more, when something was found)

Comment: why my script is not working

Comment: Obviously you'll need to tell *what* is not working for you

Comment: It does not find any key although they are present

Comment: Does this work for you: http://pastebin.com/wZeLWnKv ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75500/discussion-between-ankit-and-hek2mgl).